# Java - Trying to use .setBytes function for SQLite but getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds 0 error

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, blob

I am trying to insert an image as a blob into the database and first i create the image as a ByteArrayOutsream which I then proceed to use in my prepared statement as a parameter , however I am getting the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` error and I have checked that the array length and values are all correct so I don't know what position is trying to access in the array in order to give me this error

Here is my code:

```
public Boolean insertIntoProducts(String name, String description, String filePath, Double price, int quantity) {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/User/Desktop/MyDatabase.db";
        Boolean success = false;
        String sqlSelectID = "SELECT ID FROM Products ORDER BY ID DESC";
        filePath = filePath.replace("\\", "/");
        // Establishing a connection to the database
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Products(ID,Name,Description,Quantity,Price,Image,isAuthorised) "
                            + "VALUES (" + quantity + ",'" + name + "','" + description + "'," + quantity + ",'" + price
                            + "','?','0');";
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
            PreparedStatement pstatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            File image = new File(filePath);
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(image);
            ByteArrayOutputStream barray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            for(int readNum; (readNum = input.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                barray.write(buffer, 0 , readNum);
            }
            input.close();
            int i = barray.toByteArray().length;
            byte[] array = new byte[i];
            array = barray.toByteArray();
            pstatement.setBytes(1, array);
            pstatement.executeUpdate();
            success = true;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause());   
        }

        return success;
    }
```

I am getting the error at line  `pstatement.setBytes(1, array);`

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. Your problem seems to come from using `'?'` which is a **literal** for the question mark, you need to use `?` (not quotes) which signifies a **parameter**. You seem to know how to use prepared statements, then why are you concatenating values into your query string anyway? That is **unsafe**. Use parameters for **all** dynamic values.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you so much it works!!! Okay thank you for the comment about the parameters as well I am going to use the .set function for all of them. Thank you again!

Comment: @kishore Technically that seems to be a bug though, as the driver should not have thrown an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but a `SQLException` instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes i was wondering as well why the error was `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` where it should had been that there is nothing to set at parameterindex 1